# Pygame FPS faster than what I want

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to run a game at 80 fps but I am getting 83 fps?! What's going on?

```
while 1:
  start = time()
  clock.tick_busy_loop(80)
  self.update()
  fps=int(1./(time()-start))
  print fps, 'fps'
>> 83 fps
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Resolution of pygame clock = 1 msec
80 fps = 12.5 msec
83 fps = 12 msec
int(12.5) = 12
```

Comment: Is that how int works?? I am doing int on the fps not on the time.. I would expect your results if I did:
dt=int(time()-start)
fps=1./dt

Comment: As @stark says in line 1, the resolution of the Pygame clock is 1 millisecond. To get a framerate of exactly 80 FPS, it would need to draw a new frame every 12.5ms. It can't do that, so it floors/rounds it to 12ms, giving you `1 / 0.012 = ` 83 and one third FPS (which you then cast to `int`, resulting in 83).